Tiles making popping sounds and becoming loose
I have woken up to endless popping sounds in my lounge area (upper floor of the house that was recently extended) and upon investigation, I realised that it’s my tiles making that noise. When I walk on them they feel like they are loose and some have sunk in, caving the cement around them. The tiles are 600x600 porcelain tiles.
Kindly advise what could be causing this issue and how I can fix it. I put the tiles in October 2022, hence they are fairly new. Do I need to re do the whole how use or only the lounge area?
Also, must I buy new tiles or the tiler can reuse the ones I currently have?
I just want to get some feedback so that I can ask the tiler the right questions when he comes to view the problem. Could this be a bad job done when installing the tiles, sub-floor or structural issues related?
PS: the initial tiler I used came highly recommended and charged me the market rate for the job, hence I didn’t try to cut corners with this project. I’m so disappointed that the job that was done in 2022 is not as solid as I thought.

What is the surface (subfloor) under the tiles? It sounds like the proper subsurface and /or mortar was not used.  But more information is needed. Also where is the world are you?

Sounds to me like either the substrate isn't rigid enough, or there wasn't enough thinset used.

The odds of being able to get the existing tiles up and in a reusable state are probably pretty small. Unless, of course, there wasn't enough thinset used, in which case they might all just pop right off and be reusable with a bit of light scraping.

Look back on the scope of work with the tiler. Were they supposed to verify the condition of the floor? Also did this job require any engineering? For instance, does this lounge contain a grand piano but the upper floor was some unpermitted addition that was grandfathered in over time?

Do I need to re do the whole how use or only the lounge area? ... why do you expect people to know the floor plan of your house?
